# A program won't come to the foreground (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey

I have a program ([QGIS](https://qgis.org), which uses QT5) that will not come to the foreground.  It starts maximized (that's fine) but it stays behind all my other programs.  It can be focused, and I can work in QGIS, but any non-minimized programs stay in front of it.

I have tried the AutoHotKey script suggested in an answer in this post:
[Program windows won't come to foreground when selected in Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/878434/program-windows-wont-come-to-foreground-when-selected-in-windows-8-1) but it didn't help.

Comment: You may during the window's creation add the Qt flag of `WindowStaysOnTopHint`.

Comment: Is that a command line flag?  Also, this is new behavior, this program worked just fine up until a few weeks ago.  Uninstalling / reinstalling has not helped.

Comment: No, the program has to be modified to add the flag.

Comment: I'd rather not re-compile the program, and I don't think it a problem with the program itself, it works just fine on other machines.  I think something has gone sideways with my Windows profile.  I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't involve wiping and starting a new profile.

Comment: You may try a new profile.